# Make shared pointer point to a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr

Just started working with shared pointers and tried an example program like this:

```
int x = 10;
shared_ptr<int> ptr = make_shared<int>(x);
*ptr = 11;
cout<< x << " " << *ptr;
```

The result is 10 11 which didn't make sense to me since ptr was pointing to x and hence the value of x should have been changed to 11. Can someone please explain here? Also I would need the value of x to be changed when a shared pointer to it is changed. Please let me know how I can achieve that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"ptr was pointing to x"* - no it wasn't (and it never can). It points to the object *allocated* by `make_shared<int>`. the *value* of that object was supplied by `x` via the constructor arg portion of `make_shared<int>(x)`. As far as I can see, `x` is pointless here. And if you want a bunch of pointers that refer to it, simple `int *` will suffice (but I already have doubts that will solve whatever underlying problem you really have).

Comment: What you're trying to do is not sensible. If you're trying to learn how to use shared pointers, this just isn't how you use them. If you think this is the right way to solve some particular problem, you need to explain to us what that problem is. The purpose of shared pointers is to manage an object's lifetime and your `x` object has its lifetime already controlled by the fact that it has a scope.

Comment: It's a good idea to not think of the "smart pointers" as pointers at all.

Answer (score 5):

You're misunderstanding what `std::shared_ptr` provides. It is a mechanism for sharing ownership of *dynamic* data; not attaching pointers to non-dynamic data.

In your posted code, this declares a simple `int` variable with initial value of `10`

```
int x = 10;
```

Then this constructs a shared pointer to a *new* `int` whose only relationship to `x` is the value reaped from the latter to initialize the former.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(x);
```

In other words, for all intents in this code, the above is equivalent to:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(10);
```

If you want a bunch of pointers in your code to refer to `x` by address, first ask yourself why, then ask yourself why you're not just using references. I.e.

```
int x = 10;

// somewhere else
int &ref = x;
ref = 42; // will change x
```

If what you *really* want is a shared state with ownership reference counting and proper disposal mechanics therein, then you probably want:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> x = std::make_shared<int>(10);

// somewhere else
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = x;
```

With the above code, there are *two* references to a *dynamic* `int` : the shared pointer `x`, and the shared pointer `ptr`. Both have equal and shared ownership of that dynamic `int`. When either is destroyed the resource still exists, as it is still referenced by the remaining shared pointer. When the *last* outstanding reference is destroyed, so too goes the dynamic `int`.

Comment: All you say is correct and useful; you could add that "ownership" is a cipher for "responsibility to delete when done". That would make it clearer what the main purpose of smart pointers is: Controlling the lifetime of objects; from which then follows naturally why holding smart pointers to objects whose lifetime is already determined by other means does not make sense, is a contradiction and will, if you succeed (you could), disastrous.

Answer (score 2):

`make_share` constructs a new object using parameter passed to it. In this case it's x
I guess you would need `shared_ptr<int*>`. Is that what you want ??

```
int x = 10;
std::shared_ptr<int*> ptr = std::make_shared<int*>(&x);
**ptr = 11;
std::cout<< x << " " << **ptr;
```

Comment: What is the point of doing that? You can either bounce x by reference (&x) of declare x as shared_ptr<int>.

Answer (score 2):

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr = make_shared<int>(x);
```

`make_shared<int>` constructs an object of type `int` and wraps it in a `std::shared_ptr` using args as the parameter list for the constructor of `int`. So its `int` value is the *value* of `x`; it doesn't point to `x`.

It's equal to:

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr = make_shared<int>(10);
```

--

> Also I would need the value of x to be changed when a shared pointer
> to it is changed.

You can simply make `x` a `shared_ptr<int>` and share it. Or you can even just bounce x-reference: `&x`. So in any place it can by modified.  No?